# What does $X\mid Y\sim N(0,1)$ exactly mean (is $X\mid Y$ a random variable)?

Tags: probability-theory

I've seen a lot in economics model that people write assumptions like
$$
X\mid Y\sim N(0,1)
$$
with $X$ and $Y$ being random variables.

- What does $X\mid Y\sim N(0,1)$ exactly mean in mathematics? I'm wondering if it means something related to the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions). But the article in wikipedia only gives the formula
  $$
  f_X(x\mid Y=y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.
  $$
- [Added:] Does the notation suggest that the object $X\mid Y$ is a random variable?

Comment: I've never seen $X|Y\sim N(0,1)$ - as it's equivalent to saying $X\sim N(0,1)$ independent of $Y$ which would be stated instead. In econ one usually sees $X|Y\sim N(aY+b,\sigma^2)$. I think of $X|Y$ as a collection of distributions indexed by possible values of $Y$.

Comment: Re the title: no, X|Y is not a random variable, actually X|Y does not exist.

Comment: $X\mid Y$ is not a random variable. One defines the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ as the probability measure $\pi(A,y)$ satisfying $\int_B \pi(A,y) \,P_Y(\mathrm dy)=P(X\in A,Y\in B)$ for all $A,B$ (we actually also require that $\pi$ is a Markov kernel). The notation that $X\mid Y=y\sim N(0,1)$ is then simply notation for saying that $\pi(A,y)=\int_A \varphi(z)\,\mathrm dz$ for all $A$ and $y$, where $\varphi$ is the density of a standard normal distribution.

Comment: @StefanHansen: $X\mid Y=y\sim N(0,1)$ (which depends on $y$ according to the notation) makes sense for me. Are you saying $X\mid Y\sim N(0,1)$ is an invalid notation?

Comment: @Jack: I wouldn't call it invalid, but rather unusual. In fact, it means exactly the same as $X\mid Y=y\sim N(0,1)$ (because the RHS does not depend on $y$) and as already pointed out by A.S. this is equivalent to stating that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 4):

$X\mid Y \sim N(0,1)$ means that "the conditional distribution of $X$ when given $Y$ is standard normal".

So yes, in this example, it means $f_{X\mid Y} (x\mid y) = f_X(x\mid Y=y) = \phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is the Gaussian probability density function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So $f_X(x\mid Y=y)=\phi(x)$ suggest that $f_X(x\mid Y=y)$ is somehow independent of $y$?

Comment: Yes, it does to me too. @Jack

Comment: Since $f_X(x\mid Y=y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, one has $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_Y(y)\phi(x)$, this seems something related two independence of random variables.